Problem with Supabase resetPasswordForEmail Flow
The problem I have is related to resetPasswordForEmail flow.
I try to implement documentation supabase flow that indicates:
I first use,
const { error } = await supabase.auth.resetPasswordForEmail(email, {
    redirectTo: 'http://localhost:5173/actualizar-password'
});

to get the email in which a will get redirected to the page where I will update the password
Then I have to use:
const { data,error } = await supabase.auth.updateUser({
    password: newPassword
});

The problem is that I'm receiving the following error:

Error: Auth session missing!"

I'm looking for a answer to this problem, I've noticed that people use a token to solve resetPassword without signIn, however in my case my URL do not contain any token, my url look like localhost:5173/actualizar-password
I have to add that the flow works only if my session is saved in the localStorage, however if is the first time in the browser that i try to resetPassword without signIn the flow doesn't work and i get the "Error: Auth session missing!".
